# how to place text inside quotes

Tags: c#, .net, string

I'm trying to add your computer name to the name of the plugin text. Here is a example:

1. I have a path which detects file which is here:

   ```
   string pypath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
   + "\\elfen_encore\\extra_maya\\mayaplugins\\CoDMayaTools.py";
   ```
2. From there I use this code to access a string in there

   ```
   public void changepy()
   {
        if (File.Exists(pypath))
        {
           {
               string quotes = "\"\"";
               string name =  System.Environment.MachineName;
               string text = File.ReadAllText(pypath);
               text = text.Replace("\"Call of Duty Tools\"", quotes + name);

               File.WriteAllText(pypath, text + name);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Changed  ");
         }
         else
         {

         }
   ```

Then this is the file it should change to computer name :

```
OBJECT_NAMES =  {'menu'  :      ["CoDMayaToolsMenu",            
  "Call of Duty Tools",     None,                   None,                   None],
```

"CoDMayaToolsMenu" is the issue; I want to replace that with the users computer name but as you can see its in quotes and I am having huge issues on trying to get the text in the quotes. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
text = text.Replace("\"Call of Duty Tools\"", "\"" + name + "\"");
```

If not, please specify a little bit more your question or your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If you're leaving the quotes anyway, why not this approach? ... It's a bit unclear if this is what you're trying to accomplish?

```
public void changepy()
{
     if (File.Exists(pypath))
     {
         string machineName = System.Environment.MachineName;
         string content = File.ReadAllText(pypath);
         content = content.Replace("Call of Duty Tools", machineName);

         File.WriteAllText(pypath, content);

         MessageBox.Show("Changed");
     }
     else
     {
     }
}
```